# Fast compare method of 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel

**EDIT:** Instead for my solution, use something like

```
 For i = 1 To tmpRngSrcMax
     If rngSrc(i) <> rngDes(i) Then ...
 Next i
```

It is about 100 times faster.

I have to compare two columns containing string data using VBA. This is my approach:

```
Set rngDes = wsDes.Range("A2:A" & wsDes.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
Set rngSrc = wsSrc.Range("I3:I" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

tmpRngSrcMax = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cntNewItems = 0

For Each x In rngSrc

tmpFound = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngDes, x.Row)
Application.StatusBar = "Processed: " & x.Row & " of " & tmpRngSrcMax & " / " & Format(x.Row / tmpRngSrcMax, "Percent")
DoEvents ' keeps Excel away from the "Not responding" state

If tmpFound = 0 Then ' new item
    cntNewItems = cntNewItems + 1

    tmpLastRow = wsDes.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1  ' first empty row on target sheet
    wsDes.Cells(tmpLastRow, 1) = wsSrc.Cells(x.Row, 9)
End If
Next x
```

So, I'm using a For Each loop to iterate trough the 1st (src) column, and the CountIf method to check if the item is already present in the 2nd (des) column. If not, copy to the end of the 1st (src) column.

The code works, but on my machine it takes ~200s given columns with around 7000 rows. I noticed that CountIf works way faster when used directly as a formula.

Does anyone has ideas for code optimization?

Comment: You could use an O(n) algorithm if the data were sorted. That would be my optimisation approach.

Comment: Forget about using Worksheetfucntion for such huge data. Copy the data to Arrays and then do a comparison. You will be pleasantly surprised at the speed ;)

Comment: `ScreenUpdating=false` at the beginning of your code will help a little too.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Thank a lot, now we are down to <2s runtime :D Thank for the fast fix.

Comment: `200secs` to `less than 2 Secs`! Now that is what I call being pleasantly surprised ;)

Comment: after your edit, your loop is faster because it only compares the adjacent rows meaning A1 = I1, A2 = I2. This isn't what you wanted is it?

Comment: @mehow: You're right. This works here, but in general: What solution do you suggest if I would have to compare also the non-adjacent rows (= check all against all)? According to http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/ the variant array method shown 1 answer below might be the best.

Comment: @Clemens see my answer I have ran 3 different codes and compared the results

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok. Let's clarify a few things.

So column `A` has `10,000` randomly generated values , column `I` has `5000` randomly generated values. It looks like this

[image]

I have run 3 different codes against 10,000 cells.

**the `for i = 1 to ... for j = 1 to ...`** approach, the one you are suggesting

```
Sub ForLoop()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim stNow As Date
    stNow = Now

    Dim lastA As Long
    lastA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lastB As Long
    lastB = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim match As Boolean

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    For i = 2 To lastA
        Set r1 = Range("A" & i)
        match = False
        For j = 3 To lastB
            Set r2 = Range("I" & j)
            If r1 = r2 Then
                match = True
            End If
        Next j
        If Not match Then
            Range("I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = r1
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print DateDiff("s", stNow, Now)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Sid's appraoch**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsDes As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rngDes As Range, rngSrc As Range
    Dim DesLRow As Long, SrcLRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim DesArray, SrcArray, TempAr() As String
    Dim boolFound As Boolean

    Set wsDes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    DesLRow = wsDes.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    SrcLRow = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngDes = wsDes.Range("A2:A" & DesLRow)
    Set rngSrc = wsSrc.Range("I3:I" & SrcLRow)

    DesArray = rngDes.Value
    SrcArray = rngSrc.Value

    For i = LBound(SrcArray) To UBound(SrcArray)
        For j = LBound(DesArray) To UBound(DesArray)
            If SrcArray(i, 1) = DesArray(j, 1) Then
                boolFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If boolFound = False Then
            ReDim Preserve TempAr(n)
            TempAr(n) = SrcArray(i, 1)
            n = n + 1
        Else
            boolFound = False
        End If
    Next i

    wsDes.Cells(DesLRow + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(TempAr) + 1, 1).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(TempAr)
End Sub
```

**my (mehow) approach**

```
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim stNow As Date
    stNow = Now

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Range("A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

    Dim varr As Variant
    varr = Range("I3:I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

    Dim x, y, match As Boolean
    For Each x In arr
        match = False
        For Each y In varr
            If x = y Then match = True
        Next y
        If Not match Then
            Range("I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = x
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print DateDiff("s", stNow, Now)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

the results as follows

[image]

now, you select the **fast compare method** :)

---

filling in of the random values

```
Sub FillRandom()
    Cells.ClearContents
    Range("A1") = "Column A"
    Range("I2") = "Column I"

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 10002
        Range("A" & i) = Int((10002 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
        If i < 5000 Then
            Range("I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = _ 
                 Int((10002 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice analysis. Did you try something like the first suggestion made by @Reafidy? be nice to add in to your speed comparison - avoiding nested loops all together (p.s. currently nicking your method and adding to my file of useful code .... which remind me - what is the "Community Wiki"?)

Comment: @whytheq yes I did try and upvote his approach as its very fast as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here is non-looping code that executes almost instantly for the example given above from mehow.

```
Sub HTH()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,I:I,1,FALSE)"
        .Value = .Value
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16).Offset(, -1).Copy Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .ClearContents
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You can use whatever column you like as the dummy column.

Info:
[Done get caught in the loop](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm)

**Some notes on speed testing:**
Compile vba project before running test.
For Each Loops execute faster than For i = 1 To 10 loops.
If possible exit the loop if the answer is found to prevent pointless loops with Exit For.
Long executes faster than integer.

Finally a faster loop method (if you must loop but its still not as fast as the above non-looping method):

```
Sub Looping()
    Dim vLookup As Variant, vData As Variant, vOutput As Variant
    Dim x, y
    Dim nCount As Long
    Dim bMatch As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    vData = Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    vLookup = Range("I2", Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).Value

    ReDim vOutput(UBound(vData, 1), 0)

    For Each x In vData
        bMatch = False
        For Each y In vLookup
            If x = y Then
                bMatch = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next y
        If Not bMatch Then
            nCount = nCount + 1: vOutput(nCount, 0) = x
        End If
    Next x

    Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(nCount).Value = vOutput

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True      

End Sub
```

As per @brettdj comments a For Next alternative:

```
For x = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
    bMatch = False
    For y = 1 To UBound(vLookup, 1)
        If vData(x, 1) = vLookup(y, 1) Then
            bMatch = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next y
    If Not bMatch Then
        nCount = nCount + 1: vOutput(nCount, 0) = vData(x, 1)
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: +1 I like the use if the under-utilised formulae insertion.

Comment: Note though that [For each Loops through arrays are not recommended](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129931)

Comment: @brettdj, thanks for the article and you are quite correct.  How ever in this example For Each is clearly faster. ;)

Comment: can you guys make a varient that color codes the matches that are found in red?

Answer (score 2):

if you use .Value2 instead of .Value it will be a little bit faster again.

Comment: have you got *anything* to support your one sentence answer? :P

Comment: Did you try it?  There are plenty of references to this... just search if you need more convincing.  Just trying to help :)

Comment: this is tending towards a comment rather than an answer - surprised it hasn't been down-voted

Comment: @whytheq the question was about finding the fastest possible code and until you use Value2 instead of Value your are leaving money on the table. Value has a lot of overhead for processing date and currency types which Value2 doesn't have: it just blasts the numbers through. Although its well documented elsewhere, it was not not mentioned here but it's very important for fast code.

Comment: @CoolBlue - accepted... but the question (and the answers) are more focused on the algorithm used. Your "Answer" could be added to any of the existing answers as a comment, and would be a good comment which could prompt an edit of the answer. Who cares if you use value or value2 if you've got 2 nested loops and your algorithm's is running in quadratic time - to move the algorithm to logarithmic or linear time is the answer.....with some fine tuning such as your comment. Compare your answer to mehow's ....

Comment: @whytheg what is the purpose of these comments on a post from last October? It was maybe my 3rd of 4th post and sure maybe I didn't understand the forum culture very well at that stage, but fine, ok: what do you want me to do? Should I delete the post? Do you see a systematic problem with all my posts? More than happy to accept your criticism and guidance...

Comment: @CoolBlue ....like the rest of SO its no big deal - if I see something I like I say so and if I see something odd I comment - nothing personal: this is the only entry of yours that I have looked at. (chances are I'm probably being a hypocrite...if you nosed through my old answers you might find something short answers that I could have expanded on a bit!)

Comment: While I agree this is tending towards a comment, it's also very good advice that will improve coding time. Good discussion between the two of you as well - could gave so easily gone off track.

Comment: @whytheg ok, no problem. I do understand that it takes a lot of effort and cross-crytisism and collaboration to maintain the integrity of SO and the reults of this are clearly evident. I think I'm guilty of being a little bit precious on this occasion :q Your advice is noted and appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote this quickly... Can you test this for me?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsDes As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rngDes As Range, rngSrc As Range
    Dim DesLRow As Long, SrcLRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim DesArray, SrcArray, TempAr() As String
    Dim boolFound As Boolean

    Set wsDes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    DesLRow = wsDes.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    SrcLRow = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngDes = wsDes.Range("A2:A" & DesLRow)
    Set rngSrc = wsSrc.Range("I3:I" & SrcLRow)

    DesArray = rngDes.Value
    SrcArray = rngSrc.Value

    For i = LBound(SrcArray) To UBound(SrcArray)
        For j = LBound(DesArray) To UBound(DesArray)
            If SrcArray(i, 1) = DesArray(j, 1) Then
                boolFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If boolFound = False Then
            ReDim Preserve TempAr(n)
            TempAr(n) = SrcArray(i, 1)
            n = n + 1
        Else
            boolFound = False
        End If
    Next i

    wsDes.Cells(DesLRow + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(TempAr) + 1, 1).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(TempAr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Using the variant array, it works about 5 times faster than the original code. Thanks for this more general solution.

Comment: about 8-9 seconds on average run with random values. +1 to you for approach that is relatively FAST and much better than the `for` loop  and cells way of doing things

Answer (score 1):

I just tweaked Mehow to get items missing from both list.
Just in case somebody may need it. Thanks for the code sharing

```
Sub Main()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim stNow As Date
stNow = Now

Dim varr As Variant
varr = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value

Dim arr As Variant
arr = Range("I3:I" & Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value

Dim x, y, match As Boolean
For Each y In arr
    match = False
    For Each x In varr
        If y = x Then match = True
    Next x
    If Not match Then

        Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1) = y

    End If
Next
Range("B1") = "Items not in A Lists"
Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1) = "Items not in I Lists"
'Dim arr As Variant
arr = Range("A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value

'Dim varr As Variant
varr = Range("I3:I" & Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value

'Dim x, y, match As Boolean
For Each x In arr
    match = False
    For Each y In varr
        If x = y Then match = True
    Next y
    If Not match Then
        Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1) = x
    End If
Next


Debug.Print DateDiff("s", stNow, Now)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Ranges_Iguais(rgR1 As Range, rgR2 As Range) As Boolean

  Dim vRg1 As Variant
  Dim vRg2 As Variant
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

  vRg1 = rgR1.Value
  vRg2 = rgR2.Value
  i = 0

  Do
    i = i + 1
    j = 0
    Do
        j = j + 1
    Loop Until vRg1(i, j) <> vRg2(i, j) Or j = UBound(vRg1, 2)
  Loop Until vRg1(i, j) <> vRg2(i, j) Or i = UBound(vRg1, 1)

  Ranges_Iguais = (vRg1(i, j) = vRg2(i, j))

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set R1 = Range(S1.Cells(1, 1), S1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    Set R2 = Range(S2.Cells(1, 1), S2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    If R1.Count = R2.Count Then
        Set R3 = Range(S3.Cells(1, 1), S3.Cells(S2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, S2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column))
        R3.Formula = "=" & R1.Address(, , , True) & "=" & R2.Address(, , , True)
        Set R = R3.Find(What:="FALSE", After:=S3.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
        bComp = R Is Nothing
    Else
        bComp = False
    End If
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?