# Fast merging duplicates in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro in Excel to mergue duplicated rows:

The idea is that if 2 rows or more have the same A B C columns, I mergue their D columns removing ABC duplicates.
I need to do this, but checking more colums.

My macro looks like this:

```
processingRow = 2
Do Until Cells(processingRow, 1).Value = ""
    i = processingRow + 1

    Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
       If Cells(processingRow, 8) = Cells(i, 8) And _
          Cells(processingRow, 12) = Cells(i, 12) And _
          Cells(processingRow, 7) = Cells(i, 7) And _
          Cells(processingRow, 6) = Cells(i, 6) And _
          Cells(processingRow, 5) = Cells(i, 5) And _
          Cells(processingRow, 4) = Cells(i, 4) And _
          Cells(processingRow, 3) = Cells(i, 3) And _
          Cells(processingRow, 2) = Cells(i, 2) And _
          Cells(processingRow, 1) = Cells(i, 1) Then
               If Cells(i, 14) <> "" Then
                    Cells(processingRow, 14) = Cells(processingRow, 14) & "," & Cells(i, 14)
               End If
               Rows(i).Delete


        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    processingRow = processingRow + 1

Loop
```

When running the macro with 500 rows, it takes a while, but its still reasonable. But I need to run this macro in a excel with more than 2500 rows, and it takes so much time that its not practical anymore.

This is my first macro in excel using VBA, so I was wondering if there is a faster way to process rows/cells, since accessing them individually seems extremelly slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: see [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567060/excel-vba-fast-compare-method-of-2-columns/19570501#19570501) to get an idea of what to do.

Comment: The problem I see is that in that example, you only compare the contents of one column to another. But I need to compare several columns in a row. If I used a "for each" to iterate through a range of columns and rows, it iterates through all the cells, instead of iterating though rows.

Comment: does your macro fail anywhere? does it give an error? what is your specific question?

Comment: The problem is that my macro is extremelly slow when I have to process +2500 rows. I understand it is beause I'm accessing each cell individually, instead of loading chunk of data from the excel. I think the Range functio would be really useful, but I really fail to understand how to use the returned value from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:** I missed that you weren't checking every column to determine what was a duplicate.  This should be closer now:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim rngCheck As Range, rw As Range
Dim dict As Object, k As String, rwDup As Range
Dim rngDel As Range, tmp

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngCheck = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
                              .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 14)
    End With

    For Each rw In rngCheck.Rows

        k = RowKey(rw)
        If dict.exists(k) Then
            Set rwDup = dict(k)
            tmp = rw.Cells(14).Value
            If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
                rwDup.Cells(14).Value = rwDup.Cells(14).Value & "," & tmp
            End If
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = rw
            Else
                Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, rw)
            End If
        Else
            dict.Add k, rw
        End If

    Next rw

    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

'create a "key" for the row by joining all columns to be checked
Function RowKey(rw As Range) As String
    Dim arr, x As Long, sep As String, rv As String
    arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12)
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        rv = rv & sep & rw.Cells(arr(x)).Value
        sep = Chr(0)
    Next x
    RowKey = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this piece of code seems to be doing nothing. Keep in mind that the values of the 14 column are different for each duplicate, and from what i can tell from the code, it is also added to the dictionary, which makes no duplicates to be fund (even if all previous 13 columns are the same). How could I keep the 14th column out ouf the dictionary?

Comment: One more question: Why do you transpose the rows twice?

Comment: The double Transpose is to create a 1-D array from the row on the worksheet, so you can give it to Join().  I don't know why it's not working for you - in my testing (based on my read of what you wanted to do) it worked fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams: the code crashes when I try to run on 65000 rows. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Crashes how *exactly* - on which line and with what error number and message ?

Comment: [Not Responding] appears on the title bar after 1-2 mins and then Excel restarts. I tried using breakpoints to find the error. It works beautifully and gives expected results, but as soon as I remove breakpoints it hangs. I guess it's a problem to do with the amount of data?