# Alter Macro that matches two cols across sheets to return entire row not just the match

Tags: excel, vba

I managed to alter the original macro by @simoco here: [How to apply "found" Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315356/how-to-apply-found-macro) to match across sheets.

I also need to return not just the match but the entire row of the match and this I can not figure out how to do, as the macro is it returns the matched cell string for all the inserted row cells across the cols E:O

```
Sub Main()
Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long, lastrowB As Long
Dim match As Boolean
Dim k As Long
Dim arr, varr, v, a, res

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set wsS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set wsT = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)


    lastrow = wsS.Range("B" & wsS.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowB = wsT.Range("B" & wsT.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    arr = wsS.Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Value
    varr = wsT.Range("B2:B" & lastrowB).Value

    wsT.Range("E:O").EntireColumn.Insert
    wsT.Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "name"


k = 1

ReDim res(1 To lastrowB, 1 To 1)

For Each v In varr
    match = False
    'if value from column D (v) contains in column B
    For Each a In arr
        If a = v Then
            match = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next a

    If match Then
        res(k, 1) = v
    Else
        res(k, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If
    k = k + 1
Next v

With wsT
    .Range("E2:O" & lastrowB).Value = res
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: are you trying to return the row that is referenced by v if match=TRUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the row in worksheet 2 referenced by v if match = TRUE, insert the following line after `res(k, 1) = v`:

```
  myRowResult = wsS.Rows(k + 1)
```

This will set myRowResult as that entire row. You'll need to do k + 1 here because your sheets have headers, but k starts with 1. In other words, if you just do `wsS.Rows(k)`, you'll get the row above the row that is matched.

You can then use myRowResult in your code as desired.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, sorry it took me so long to get back here.