# Excel VBA for hiding cells in one sheet if they match cells in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, row

I am new to VBA and am having problems learning the rules of variables (I think that's the problem here).

I have two worksheets in a spreadsheet.  I need to make code that automatically hides a row on worksheet 2 if that same value in column a is on worksheet 1, column a.

Here's one of the variations of code I've tried:

```
Dim Sheet2Value As Variant
Dim Sheet1Value As Variant
'
Sheet2Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Value
Sheet1Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Value
'
If Sheet2Value = Sheet1Value Then
    Sheets("BMAC=N").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Sheets("BMAC=N").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

I get a type mismatch error but I'm not sure exactly why.  I chose variant because I don't know what I'm doing, but both columns in excel will be set to "General".

Can anyone help with this?  What concept am I missing?

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Are the entries on `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` numbers? Words (i.e. strings)? You've got the gist of this one down, but will need to loop through the ranges cell-by-cell to compare values

Comment: They will be numbers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. you cannot compare entire column:

   ```
   Sheet2Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Value
   ```

   you need to loop through the collection of cells, see this: [Fast compare method of 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567060/excel-vba-fast-compare-method-of-2-columns)
2. you cannot hide row without defining a range to hide

   ```
   Sheets("BMAC=N").Range("Some_address").EntireRow.Hidden
   ```
3. Finally, i'd suggest to change your code to shortest way:

   ```
   Sheets("BMAC=N").Range("A1").EntireRow.Hidden = (value1<>value2)
   ```

Good luck!