# is there a faster way to search through two different length ranges in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of id's in one range and I need to count the number of these id's that appear in another range.  The ranges are of different lengths, or I would use `countifs`.

I've written the following code, but its very slow:

```
Function find_in_two_ranges_two_sheets(ws1 As String, col1 As Integer, ws2 As String, col2 As Integer)
    'first find if is in one range, then count if it in another range

    '  *** set up range of first worksheet ***
    Dim rows1 As Integer
    rows1 = Get_Rows_Generic(ws1, 1) ' get the number of rows on the first sheet
    Dim range1 As Range ' range of first search

    With Worksheets(ws1)
        Set range1 = .Range(.Cells(1, col1), .Cells(rows1, col1)) ' set the range being searchedin the first sheet
    End With

    '   *** set up range of second worksheet ***
    Dim rows2 As Integer
    rows2 = Get_Rows_Generic(ws2, 1) ' get the number of rows in second worksheet

    Dim range2 As Range
    With Worksheets(ws2)
        Set range2 = .Range(.Cells(1, col2), .Cells(rows2, col2)) ' set the range being searched in second sheet
    End With


    Dim constructed_id As String ' the raw string found in the first column
    Dim found2 As Range ' this will be used as the query in the second range.

    '   *** set up counting variables ***
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0

     '   *** loop through ranges in first sheet and count the number of times each id is found in second sheet ***
    For n = 1 To 300 ' rows1
        constructed_id = "ObjectID(" & range1(n, 1) & ")"
        Set found2 = range2.Find(constructed_id, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not found2 Is Nothing Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next n

    find_in_two_ranges_two_sheets = counter

End Function


Sub test_stuff()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = find_in_two_ranges_two_sheets("invitesOutput.csv", 3, "propertyOutput.csv", 3) 
    MsgBox "counter totaled " & x
End Sub
```

Any way I can speed this up?

Comment: Is the range just one column? If so you can still use the `COUNTIFS` function. Other thought is if it's more than one column and you wanted to use VBA, you could iterate through each column and add it to a variable.

Comment: you may wanna go through [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19567060/2140173)

Comment: The way to do it, per the answers referenced by @MichalKrzych is to use `countif` in place of the `.find` meathod.  If `countif`' returns more than 0, then I add to the counter.  Very helpful.  Please add as answer and I'll check it off.  Thanks!

Comment: @dwstein if you think your answer is going to be different then the one referenced please add an answer yourself :) If you don't think you need a different answer you may as well just delete this question as it's a bit localized imo.