# Comparing and Organizing 2 Adjacent Columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, comparison

I am trying to compare 2 adjacent columns in Excel and organize them according to size. I want to compare cells A1 and B1, and if cell A1 > cell B1, switch cells A1 and B1. If cell A1 < cell B1 do nothing. I want to do this for thousands of rows, and compare the 2 cells in every row, and make adjustments accordingly with a macro. 
Ex.

```
2|3 goes to 2|3
4|1 goes to 1|4
7|5 goes to 5|7
```

I found a question on here that is similar: [Fast compare method of 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567060/fast-compare-method-of-2-columns)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is a picture I found on the link that I am trying to build off of. It doesn’t do exactly what I want but I figured it was close to a framework for what I am trying to do! Preferably the macro won’t take a particularly long time.

[image]

Comment: Where is the example data and expected output? Where is your effort so far? Please edit your question accordingly. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas to improve your question. Just include the text for the code marked as text. Images don't help much.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code formatted as code block instead of an image. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub kjkj()
     With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
         Dim rng As Range
         Set rng = .Range("A1:B3") 'Change to your range

         Dim arr As Variant
         arr = rng.Value

         Dim outArr
         ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To UBound(arr, 2))

         Dim i As Long
         For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 2) Then
                outArr(i, 1) = arr(i, 2)
                outArr(i, 2) = arr(i, 1)
            Else
                outArr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1)
                outArr(i, 2) = arr(i, 2)
            End If
        Next i

        rng.Value = outArr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Erik wrote: *Preferably the macro won’t take a particularly long time.*
To speed up the loop by Scott Craner you can replace Dim i as Long to Dim i as Integer if the number of rows are less than 32768. Also replace  For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) with Dim n as Integer, n = UBound(arr, 1), For i = 1 To n ... etc ...

Comment: There is no speed difference between `Long` and `Integer`.  Nor do I believe that assigning the Ubound to a variable will make a difference as the call is done only once not each time for the loop. @peakpeak

Comment: Any reason I am getting a type mismatch? I just wanted to sort numbers, which are all integers. Sorry I am new to VBA.

Comment: I think the issues is with the type variant

Comment: No, Again on which line is the error happening? @ErikMarlyk

Comment: Variant is needed when loading in bulk from/to a range.  So it is not that.  Most likely your data has errors in it. or some of the numbers are stored as text and not true numbers. @ErikMarlyk

Comment: There is no line highlighted or mentioned. I get a pop up that says “Type Mismatch” and no debug option on the pop up. I am using a blank workbook labelled sheet one with data in the A and B columns. The data consists of single digit integers of varying values.